# How to determine when to display an ajax loader with Redux + Apollo Client

Tags: redux, react-redux, apollostack, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a global loader element. The loader spins when the app performs any network operation. I recently integrated with Apollo Client but I am not entirely sure entirely the best approach for examining whether Apollo is currently fetching.

According to the [docs](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html#basics), there is a `loading` property that is passed along with data as props to the component using the `graphql` HOC. The problem is that my loader exists on the top most level in a component that does not utilize the `graphql` HOC.

The way I see it, I will probably need to examine the `state` object to see when a query exists with `loading` set to true. Is this a sound approach?

Here is what my data looks like for reference:

[image]

Another alternative I can think of is to perform the query on my parent component.

For reference, I am using Apollo Client in a React-Redux environment.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?